# How to get the correct output from this for / if loop

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

*Im currently having some hard time with a for loop combined with an if loop. I'm not getting the right output right now and perhaps you can help me find the clue.*

*The for loop, loops through all my cards, each card gets a cardnumber, beginning from 0 and increment +1 each time*.

*Each card got a name of the person who owns the card.*

***Problem: If i input the selected number, i need to print not only the selected card but also all the other cards owned by the name.***

**How i'm receiving the input:**

```
System.out.println("Enter your card number: ");
int cardnumber = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

**The Current Loop:**

```
for(Card c: cardlist) {                              

    if(c.toString().contains(cardlist.getCard(cardnumber).toString())){
    System.out.println(c.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output right now**

```
// Input: 0

Cardnumber: 0
Name: Lars
```

**The output i want to achieve**

```
// Input: 0, only print cards with name Lars

Cardnumber: 0
Name: Lars

Cardnumber: 1
Name: Lars

Cardnumber: 5 
Name: Lars
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make much more sense to enter the name instead?

Comment: What is the implementation of Card ?

Comment: Can you show your card class? Do you have a getName() method?

Comment: Give me a moment i'll add the Card class and i do have a getName() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. So, the user inputs a card number X, and the program should list all the cards owned by the person owning the card X. So, that's what you should implement. In pseudo code:

```
Card cardX = findCardWithNumber(x);
String owner = cardX.getOwner();
for (Card card: allCards) {
    if (card.getOwner().equals(owner)) {
        System.out.println(card);
    }
}
```